# How do I simplify this header with lines on the side, so that it doesn't need css3 background properties?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, html-heading

I have a css class for centering a heading, and adding vertically centered lines on either side. Problem is, it uses css3 background properties, and not every browser supports those. So I'd like to simplify this for cross browser compatibility, but am not sure how to do that.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this, **without the css3 background** (and **without adding any extra elements or static heights/widths**)?

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/dASCv/6/)

```css
.section-heading {
  display: table;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.section-heading:before {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black) no-repeat left center / 95% 1px;
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}

.section-heading:after {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black) no-repeat right center / 95% 1px;
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="section-heading">Example</h2>
```

Comment: Weird thing is that it doesn't work when I just specify a black background..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is my best try.

I have a little isue that I have corrected in Chrome; but I really don't know even why it works.

The CCS is

```
.test {
     display: table-row;
     white-space: nowrap;
     line-height: 0px;
}

.test:before,
.test:after {
     border-color: transparent;
     border-top: solid black 1px;
     border-left: solid transparent 1px;
     border-bottom: solid rgba(0,0,0,0.01) 11px;
     border-right: solid transparent 1px;
     content: "";
     display: table-cell;
     width: 50%;
}

.test:before {
     border-right: solid 30px transparent;
}
.test:after {
     border-left: solid 30px transparent;
}
```

I am using the border to display the black line, and to have it positioned in place I have reduced the height of the table to 0.

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U4tKn/)

In the fiddle, I have kept your original demo, so that you can compare side by side.

And now, the weird part. change rgba(0,0,0,0.01) in the border bottom to rgba(0,0,0,0.001), and it will break (at least in Chrome).

I really would like to understand that ...

**new answer**

All the above was asuming that the requirement was to have a transparent style (that is , that it was posible to set a background that could be seen thru the h1. If this is not the case, there is another posible solution, using box-shadow instead of gradient barckground:

```
.test {
  display: table-row;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.test:before,
.test:after {
  border: solid white 10px;
  content: "";
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  line-height: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px white, inset 0px 6px black;
}

.test:before {
  border-right-width: 10px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
.test:after {
  border-left-width: 10px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

### [new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U4tKn/8/)

Comment: Interesting! You can simplify it to this: http://jsfiddle.net/U4tKn/1/. Only the padding on the side of the header isn't working in this one, don't know how to get that..

Comment: Also, in chrome it is probably rounding the bottom border's opacity to 0.

Comment: I found out that you can apply padding on the side like this: http://jsfiddle.net/U4tKn/2/. Only thing remaining is pulling the lines to the sides of the container like the original..

Comment: It can be done with transforms (http://jsfiddle.net/U4tKn/3/) but I guess that will go against the requirement about avoiding CSS3 ...

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought about that. I updated the transforms with the other prefixes: http://jsfiddle.net/U4tKn/4/. I guess this is probably the only way to do it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am little bit deceived about ending using a transform ... I would like to find a less "CSS3" and more "CSS" solution

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/U4tKn/5/, I was thinking of pulling it to either side with negative margins, but that doesn't work either. I guess because some of the fixed measurements?

Comment: I has already explored that posibility. You would need width: calc(100% + 2em) , and your supported browsers isn't any better ...

Comment: This way: http://jsfiddle.net/U4tKn/7/, it works without css3, but it is not dynamic. If there is a way to make the white background adapt to the text in the header, then it would be possible. Maybe setting the white background to the .test class, but then you would have to find a way to make it overlap the border. Any ideas?

Comment: Added new answer using box-shadow. Not so much better in old browsers support, though

Answer (score 6):

You can use fieldset and legend, it's not very beautiful code but you don't need CSS3

http://jsfiddle.net/dASCv/9/

```css
fieldset {
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
}

legend {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    <h2>Example</h2>
  </legend>
</fieldset>
```

---

OR this other method whit `:after` and `:before`

http://jsfiddle.net/dASCv/10/

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

h2:before,
h2:after {
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  content: " ";
  width: 40%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 1.4em;
}

h2:after {
  right: 0;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>text TEXT</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: It does look a little different though. I think I'd like to stay closer to the h2 element, since that makes a little more semantic sense. I'm already not too thrilled about using display:table, and moving even further away from that would not be preferable in my opinion..

Comment: +1 for an innovative answer. But semantically, it may not be advisable.

Comment: I have update with a second method which has better semantic :)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately it still requires an extra element and doesn't dynamically adapt to the width of the text..

Comment: You cannot go with pseudo elements, no extra tags, no background . with h2 only and a text node inside it, it is not possible with css 3,

Answer (score 1):

### 1-element solution

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/nE542/1/)**

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
  margin-top: -9px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>A header</div>
```

(**NB:** for this solution to work, you need to set text-align:center on its parent element)

---

### 2-element solution (works over a background image)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/wrumL/)**

```css
.splitHR {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.splitHRText {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.splitHRText:before,
.splitHRText:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.73em;
  border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
}

.splitHRText:before {
  right: 100%;
}

.splitHRText:after {
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="splitHR">
  <span class="splitHRText">A header</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm looking for a way that does not require extra tags. Quote from the question: *and without adding any extra elements or sacrificing functionality*.

Comment: sorry, didn't see that bit.. shame though as it's a good method.

Comment: does it need to work over a background image (ie non-plain color background) - or is that not necessary?

Comment: It would be nice, but it's not necessary.

Comment: @Sam - I added a 1-element solution

Comment: Thanks, that's the best solution so far. Unfortunately it still requires styling of the parent element.

Comment: Yeah, it requires me to reset the text alignment for all other children. A self contained solution is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Yeah I know, it's a difficult one. Was hoping that someone here would have a solution to it, but it seems to be pretty impossible. Maybe with some flexbox magic or something, but that's not really something widely supported..

Answer (score 0):

Please add `Prefix` for the CSS

For Webkit browswers

```
 -webkit-gradient
```

Firefox

```
-moz-linear-gradient
```

IE

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#cccccc', endColorstr='#000000');
```

More Details Here  http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient

Comment: Yeah, I know, I just thought I'd keep it basic for the example. Also, this is not really an answer to my question. Maybe make it a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Using this way also you can achieve the answer, please check this

```
<p style="display:block; width:100%; text-align:center; 
border-bottom:1px #ccc solid; line-height:3px">
 <span style="background-color:red; ">Examples</span></p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dASCv/11/

Comment: Sorry, but I'm looking for a way that does not require extra tags. Quote from the question: *and without adding any extra elements or sacrificing functionality*.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
h2 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h2 span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    bottom: -15px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

markup

```
<h2><span>text Textsssssssssssssssss</span></h2>
```

You could set the bottom for span in percentage if you set the height for h2.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm looking for a way that does not require extra tags. Quote from the question: *and without adding any extra elements or sacrificing functionality*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code:

[**JsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/dASCv/14/)

HTML:

```
<h2><span>Title is here</span></h2>
```

CSS:

```
h2{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:30px;
}
h2 span{
    background:#fff;
    padding:0 10px;
}
h2:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    border-top:1px solid black;
    margin-top:-15px;
}
```

---

**Update:**

you can use this code too: *(single element)*

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohsen4887/dASCv/16/)

HTML:

```
<h2>Title is here</h2>
```

CSS:

```
h2{
display: table;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align: center;
line-height: 30px;
padding: 0 10px;
background: #FFF;
}
h2:after{
   content:"";
    display:block;
    border-top:1px solid;
    margin-top:-15px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

Comment: Read the question. No extra elements.

Comment: This way the lines no longer dynamically adjust to the height of the text (it sacrifices functionality). Thank you for trying, but unfortunately it is not an answer to my question.

Comment: @Sam: are you trying to plow field with spoon? you can give some style to other elements and make it easier for yourself. why you are insist on having style just with single element ?